# Enable maven3 extension only on specified profile(s)

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-extension

I have an extension I use in my Maven 3 build that outputs build information for me. It's a bit verbose so I would like to run it only in some build profiles. But `<extensions>` are only allowed in the main `<build>` and not in the profiles.

So my question is two fold. First, is there already a way to limit the extension to run only in specific profile(s) with something I can do in the `pom.xml`? Second, if not, then how should I implement this?

My initial thought was to call `mavenSession.getCurrentProject().getActiveProfiles()` and compare that to the list of profiles I want to run the extension on. But then I need to somehow pass the profile information there.. I'd like to do that in the `pom.xml` rather than from the command line but I'm not sure where should this info be stored.

Comment: Old question, but I added [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36253007/5606016) a trick to add/change a build extension via profile, hopefully worth for some future visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that should work is to use a property containing a comma-separated profile name list, ideally named in a way to make the connection obvious (i.e. «extension-artifactId».run-for-profiles). Then pass that either via -D, or put it in the <properties> section to define a project default.

Comment: I went with your suggestion as I wasn't able to find a common way to pass arguments to extensions.

Comment: @vertti I have also encountered the same issue and I'm not quite sure I understood the proposed solution. Could you please add more details?

Comment: @forhas I implemented this to a maven plugin called `maven-build-utils`. You can checkout this [commit](https://github.com/lkoskela/maven-build-utils/commit/99a99016521b4666c061d7e317d1c48174520054) for all the details. Hope that helps.